# Join an array to create JSON dynamically

Tags: bash, shell-script, json

Declaring JSON in bash is kind of annoying because you have to escape a lot of characters.

Say I have an array like this:

```
 value1="foo"
 value2="bar"
 arr=("key1" "$value1" "key2" "$value2")
```

Is there a way to somehow join the array with ":" and "," characters.

The only thing I can think of is a loop where you add the right characters, something like this:

```
data="";

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    data="$data\"$i\""
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/), which makes it easy to generate JSON on the command line:

```
$ jo -p key1="$value1" key2="$value2"
{
   "key1": "foo",
   "key2": "bar"
}
```

or, depending on what you want the end result to be,

```
$ jo -a -p "$(jo key1="$value1")" "$(jo key2="$value2")"
[
   {
      "key1": "foo"
   },
   {
      "key2": "bar"
   }
]
```

Note that `jo` will also properly encode the values in the strings `$value1` and `$value2`.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -MJSON -e 'print JSON->new->pretty(1)->encode({@ARGV})' -- "${arr[@]}"
{
   "key2" : "bar",
   "key1" : "foo"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out heredoc might be the best way to declare dynamic JSON, but I didn't know about that technique when developed the following.

This is one solution, use it like so:

```
join_arry_to_json a b c d
{"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

this will only work for strings, not for numbers or booleans.
Now to declare a boolean or a number, you use the `^` symbol:

```
ql_join_arry_to_json a ^3 b ^true c dog
```

yields:

```
{"a":3,"b":true,"c":"dog"}
```

the code is here:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/a4e3948b0ce9c22752c759d7e694c9ab